# Running mix ecto seeds files in umbrella app

Tags: elixir, ecto

A number of Ecto mix tasks work at the top level of an umbrella app. Can the seeds.exs files be run at the top level of the umbrella? I would like to add the `mix ecto.reset` alias to the umbrella. I can run the `drop`, `create` and `migrate` task. But I can't figure out how to run the seeds file of each app.

I'd like to understand how others solve this problem.

Comment: `mix run apps/p/priv/repo/seeds.exs` works. Or do you want to run all the seeds.exs with a single command?

Comment: Ultimately I would like to run them all from one command. However, I will need to control the order they are run.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old but I needed to do this earlier today and came up with a small solution that may help others with the same problem.

@Mike Buhot answer is good but I didn't want to create a task or a module and I also wanted to use the seeds.exs file that was present in the top level priv folder.
Just add the following snippet to your top-level seeds.exs and it will run all the seeds you may have across your umbrella apps.

```
umbrella_directory = "./apps/"
seeds_path = "/priv/repo/seeds.exs"

umbrella_directory
|> File.ls!()
|> Enum.filter(&File.dir?(Path.join(umbrella_directory, &1)))
|> Enum.each(fn(directory) ->
  app_seeds = Path.join([umbrella_directory, directory, seeds_path])
  case File.exists?(app_seeds) do
    true -> Mix.Tasks.Run.run([app_seeds])
    _ -> :ok
  end
end)
```

Then running `$ mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A custom recursive mix task might work

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Seed do
  use Mix.Task

  @recursive true

  def run(_args) do
    Mix.Tasks.Run.run(["priv/repo/seeds.exs"])
  end
end
```